# Link classes together

Tags: php, oop

I creating PHP applications and I have question about architecture.

I have some *systems* in my app.
For example, *Cache system*, *Output system*, *Applications system*, etc.
Also I have *Registry* for link this systems together.

Here is example of using *Cache* in *Applications*:

```
class Manager {

    public function __construct() {
        $registry = \Jx\System\JxRegistry::getInstance();
        $this->JxCache = $registry -> JxCache;
    }

    public function getAppInfo($JxId) {
        $someInfo = $this->JxCache->Applications->$JxId;
    }

}
```

But this way I need to call *Registry* everywhere and I need to create local variables to store objects.

I have another idea, something like this:

```
class Kernel {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->JxCache = new JxCache;
    }
}
/* .. */
new Kernel();
/* .. */
class Manager extends Kernel {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function getAppInfo($JxId) {
        $someInfo = $this->JxCache->Applications->$JxId; //JxCache declared in class 'Kernel'
    }

}
```

Which variant more right?
Can you suggest your variants?
Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii framework has a different approach may be you can like it:

[Yii behaviors](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/#hh1)

Comment: Ok, I understood. This is unique 'ID' (?) of behavior. Thank you, Ivan, but I want some more variants...

Comment: They're lables, to refer to the behaviors, for example to remove.